# How should I merge monthly datasets into on dataset for cleaning?

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

I am working on a case study for a ride share. The data is broken up into monthly datasets, and in order to analyze the data over the last year I would need to merge the data. I uploaded all the data to both BigQuery and Rstudio but am unsure of the best way to make one large dataset.
I may not even have to do this, but I believe that to find trends I should have all the data in one datatable. If this is not the case then I will clean the data one month at a time.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "uploaded to RStudio". Do you mean that you have read files into it, so as you have multiple data frames, and you want to combine them into one?

Comment: If by *"uploaded to ... Rstudio"* you mean "import into R within the RStudio IDE", then [tag:rstudio] is not right, since your question is most likely about how to use it in R. If you mean "upload to an instance of RStudio Server", then again, both [tag:rstudio] and [tag:rstudio-server] are not right, as this is still about the R programming language. Either way, I think this question needs focus and details to be closer to "reproducible" so that somebody can try to help.

Comment: Yes I'm using R through Rstudio cloud and I loaded the data into the files tab so I can import it in to the environment panel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `purrr::map_dfr()`? It's like `lapply()` and `rbind()` rolled into one.

```r
library(tidyverse)

all_the_tables <- 
  map_dfr( # union as it loops over the function
    .x = list.files(pattern = ".csv"), # input for the function
    .f = read_csv # the function
  )
```

If it's more complicated and you need something to vary the source by you can use something like.

```r
  map_dfr(
    .x = list.files(pattern = ".csv"),
    .f = # the tilde let's you make a more complex sequence of steps
      ~read_csv(path = .x) |> 
      mutate(source = .x)

  )
```

If it's a lot of files consider using `vroom::vroom()`